# Accessing the same level JsonElements conditionally using Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a large and complex JSON object like below:

```
{
    "FDN": [{
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822548"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "FR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969007,
        "DT": "20180504123302006"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822549"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "AR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969008,
        "DT": "20180504123302007"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822550"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "FR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969009,
        "DT": "20180504123302007"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822551"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "AR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969010,
        "DT": "20180504123302008"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822552"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "FR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969011,
        "DT": "20180504123302009"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822553"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "FR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969012,
        "DT": "20180504123302010"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822554"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "FR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969013,
        "DT": "20180504123302010"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822573"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "AR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969065,
        "DT": "20180504080929368"
    }, {
        "OT": 0,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822573"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "AR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969066,
        "DT": "20180504080929369"
    }, {
        "OT": 1,
        "CL": [{
            "K": [{
                "FID": 348,
                "VAL": "20822574"
            }, {
                "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                "VAL": "AR"
            }]
        }],
        "NK": null,
        "SS": 0,
        "ITID": "NEWS",
        "TSID": 44969067,
        "DT": "20180504082130104"
    }]
}
```

from this , I just need to consider the "CL" unit like this:

```
"CL": [{
                "K": [{
                    "FID": 348,
                    "VAL": "20822573"
                }, {
                    "FID": "LANGUAGE_ID",
                    "VAL": "AR"
                }]
            }],
```

and check if the LANGUAGE_ID is "AR", and then add the relevant value(20822573) of corresponding key "FID:348" to a list.
just an ex:

```
 if(LANGUAGE_ID.equals("AR")){
         IdList.add("20822573");
     }
```

I cant do this because both keys are in same level.

So far my code is :

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException {
        FileReader jsonReader = new FileReader(new File("json.json"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Map<String,String> fidMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonObject.class);
        JsonArray fdnJsonArray = (JsonArray) jsonObject.get("FDN");

        fdnJsonArray.forEach(jsonElement -> {
            JsonArray clJsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("CL").getAsJsonArray();
            clJsonArray.forEach(clJsonItem -> {
                JsonArray kJsonArray = clJsonItem.getAsJsonObject().get("K").getAsJsonArray();
                kJsonArray.forEach(kArrayElement -> {
                    String fid = kArrayElement.getAsJsonObject().get("FID").getAsString();
                    if(fid != null && !fid.isEmpty() && fid.equalsIgnoreCase("LANGUAGE_ID")) {
                        String val = kArrayElement.getAsJsonObject().get("VAL").getAsString();
                        System.out.println(fid + ":"+ val);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) for this.
A quick example for this particular problem to get the CL objects would be as simple as `$..CL`. Then you can manipulate the returned objects in plain java.
You can quickly prototype this online [here](http://jsonpath.com/). To further refine the jsonpath to include the language id you can check the documentation here: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2

Comment: tried but failed to get the "ID"(ex:20822573) when the language="AR".

Comment: You can still iterate over the results like you have already done, but starting straight from the elements you want. JsonPath returns JsonArray iirc.

Comment: thanks for showing me the new way of JsonPath. Finally sorted that out after struggling a bit with it.

Comment: Good to hear! JsonPath tends to be a bit of trial and error kind of thing for me as well.